# PHP Form multiple buttons

Tags: php, javascript, forms, button

I have a form with 2 buttons, that depending on which is selected will either be deleted or edited from the database. Those are each individual pages using SQL statements (questionedit and questiondelete). However, when i press a button, nothing happens...Any Ideas

Here is my javascript

```
function SelectedButton(button)
{
    if(button == 'edit')
    {
        document.testedit_questionform.action ="testedit_questionedit.php";
    }else if(button == 'delete'){
        document.testedit_questionform.action ="testedit_questiondelete.php";
    }
    document.forms[].testedit_questionform.submit();
}
```

Here is my form (being echoed from a loop)

```
<form name="testedit_questionform" action="SelectedButton" method="POST"> 
    <span class="grid_11 prefix_1" id="" >
Question:<input type="text" name="QuestionText" style="width:588px; margin-left:10px;" value="$row[0]"/>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" name="Operation" onclick="submitForm('edit')" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" name="Operation" onclick="submitForm('delete')" />
    <input type="hidden" name="QId" value="$row[3]" /><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your function should be named `submitForm`

```
function submitForm(button) {
  if(button == 'edit') {
    document.testedit_questionform.action ="testedit_questionedit.php";
  } else if(button == 'delete') {
    document.testedit_questionform.action ="testedit_questiondelete.php";
  }

  document.testedit_questionform.submit();
}
```

And then, call submit method from your form.

**EDIT:**

An alternative to calling forms is: `document.forms['FORM_NAME'].submit()`

Answer (score 1):

Look at how you access the form to call `submit()`. Now look at how you access the form to change the action. One of them is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to make one PHP file, and buttons with different names like this:

```
<form method="post" action="actions.php">
<input type="submit" name="action1" value="Action 1" />
<input type="submit" name="action2" value="Action 2" />
[...]
```

And the file actions.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["action1"])) {
     // action 1
}
elseif(isset($_POST["action2"])) {
    // action 2
}
```